# Get a reference to a element nested inside a modal

Tags: ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to get a reference to an element nested inside a modal. While using @ViewChild works for the modal, its not working for any nested elements. eg: the datePicker in the code below. Working demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s8dtmm-8gqgus (The 2nd console for datePicker is undefined)

```
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('content') modal: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('dp') datePicker: ElementRef;

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

  open() {
    this.modalService.open(this.modal);
    console.log('modal', !!this.modal); // ref to #content
    console.log('dp', this.datePicker); // undefined
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<ng-template #content let-modal>
  <input ngbDatepicker #dp="ngbDatepicker">
  <button class="calendar" (click)="dp.toggle()">Date picker</button>
</ng-template>
<button(click)="open()">Open  modal</button>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What concrete problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have a carousel instead of a datepicker and I want to be able to change it's slide number based on what I get back from the API.eg:  `carousel.activeId = "2"`

Comment: I just found a workaround by databinding to the activeId like this ` <ngb-carousel #carouselElement [activeId]="carouselActiveId" ` and setting that.

Comment: The problem is that modal contents get defined elsewhere. This guy wrote a short solution here: http://blog.ludgerpeters.com/referencing-a-viewchild-that-only-gets-injected-later-into-the-dom/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can modify your example so that the modal content is a separate component (i.e. based on [this example](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples#component) rather than [this one](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples#basic)) then you should be able to access the `datePicker` component in the `open()` method. I have created a `launch-modal.component` which defines the "Open" button and logs out the value of `dp` when the modal is opened:

**launch-modal.component.html**

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="open()">Open  modal</button>
```

**launch-modal.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbActiveModal, NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ModalComponent } from './modal.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'launch-modal-component',
  templateUrl: './launch-modal.component.html'
})
export class LaunchModalComponent {
  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

  open() {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ModalComponent);
    console.log('dp', modalRef.componentInstance.datePicker);
  }
}
```

I've then defined a `modal.component.ts` that defines the modal content (this is based  on the `app.module.html` in your question, and defines a `ViewChild` for the datePicker):

**modal.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'modal-component',
  template: `
  <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
  <input ngbDatepicker #dp="ngbDatepicker">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary calendar" (click)="dp.toggle()" type="button">Date picker</button>
  `
})
export class ModalComponent {

  @ViewChild('dp') datePicker: ElementRef;

  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {}
}
```

The output of the console when the modal is opened is:

[image]

Please see [this Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9spbwc?file=app%2Fmodal.component.ts) for a working demo.